# Isomorphism Preserves Containment on Modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, module-isomorphism

If I have a module isomorphism $\phi:M\rightarrow M'$ and modules $N\subseteq M$ in $R$, is is necessarily true that $\phi(N)\subseteq\phi(M)$ in $M'$?

I know that isomorphisms are structure preserving but I can't tell whether that extends to the actual order of the submodules.

Comment: This is true for literally any function at all.

Comment: @EricWofsey Great! I thought it was a bit of a silly question but I just wanted to make sure